# MYSQL PHP select the opposite of a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables.
One table has everything I need including a cardId(PK)
The other name is a user type table. This table stores the userId and the cardId(FK).

```
SELECT ci.cardId, ci.year, ci.name, ci.number
    FROM USERCARDS uc 
    INNER JOIN CARDINDEX ci ON uc.cardId = ci.cardId 
    WHERE uc.userId = 'USER_ID'
```

So for this query, it will display the cardId, year, name, and number from the `CARDINDEX`. It will only display the cards that the user has saved in `USERCARDS`.

I want to do the opposite. If a user is looking at, lets just say, 5 cards, but the `CARDINDEX` has 50 cards, this query will display the information for the five cards. However, for a new query, I would want to show the remaining 45 cards. Basically, they cant add a card they already are following.

I tried to have `uc.cardId != ci.cardId` but that didn't work. Im kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this as a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ci.cardId, ci.year, ci.name, ci.number
FROM CARDINDEX ci LEFT JOIN 
     USERCARDS uc 
     ON uc.cardId = ci.cardId AND
        uc.userId = 'USER_ID'
WHERE uc.cardID IS NULL;
```

Alternatively, you could write this using `NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT ci.cardId, ci.year, ci.name, ci.number
FROM CARDINDEX ci 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM USERCARDS uc 
                  WHERE uc.cardId = ci.cardId AND
                        uc.userId = 'USER_ID'
                 );
```

Comment: The NOT EXISTS worked as expected. Thank you so much!!